# Best article about how to use jQTouch 

Tags: jquery, jqtouch

I want to use jQTouch on my project, but I can't find many examples.

So do you know some website which has many jQTouch examples.

Thanks

Comment: Please note that the title of your question does match the text. You ask for an article in your title, but code samples in your question text.

Answer (score 5):

I work for sencha who funds jqtouch development. Here are the best getting started materials that people have said are useful. If you're looking for cut and paste jqtouch code then, you can look at the directory of applications on [the Google Code Group](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/PoweredBy)

If you're looking for introductory training materials, you should look at the following resources:

- Jonathan Stark (ex-maintainer) [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6X4K2MQsSeI&feature=player_embedded)
- [Peepcode's intro tutorial](http://peepcode.com/products/jqtouch) (awesome tutorials)
- The Google code [introductory page](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: I also found this demo link a very useful reference: http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/

Comment: all the links are dead.. :(

Comment: I think that reflects the status of the project pretty well

Answer (score 2):

The best introduction to jqtouch that I have found in Jonathan's starks book [Building iPhone Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/), which is currently available online for free.  The peepcode video is good, however after reading Jonathan's book I really didn't learn anything new.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look at these forks of JQTouch - they have some great new extensions, and demos as well:

http://github.com/DataZombies/jQTouch

https://github.com/beedesk/jQTouch

Comment: The first one is very good. It has "Horizontal scrolling tabbar with badges"

Answer (score 1):

I have used one thing to help me get started with jqtouch which is the related peepcode screencast: cheap (9$), very well done, complete enough, comes with working projects and source code,

I would really encourage you to check this out (and I am by no means related to peepcode, only really like their productions): http://peepcode.com/

Answer (score 0):

Peepcode screencast is a good introduction to jQTouch.