# jqTouch & Documentation

Tags: jqtouch

I'm playing around with jqTouch - a very impressive project - however, I was wondering if there was some systematic documentation I could get my hands on?

The website gives some demos, but I'm finding it very slow going having to look through the source code to figure out what class I should assign to my divs, lis, etc.

Anyone got any pointers?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real documentation per say, however check out

[Best article about how to use jQTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393003/best-article-about-how-to-use-jqtouch)

for some useful tutorials.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I think the only thing holding back mass adoption of jqTouch is the lack of concise and complete documentation. Also, it would really be great if there was an Aptana/Zend plug-in.